# Apache Spark: how to view the log file?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Apache Spark and started the master under Debian 10.  I would like to review the log file, however am having trouble.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Are the jar libraries located somewhere else?

[This site](https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/how-to-setup-an-apache-spark-cluster/) suggests:

```
$ java -cp $SPARK_HOME/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host localhost --port 7077 --webui-port 8080                           
Error: Could not find or load main class .opt.spark.jars.aircompressor-0.10.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /opt/spark/jars/aircompressor-0/10/jar
```

I tried the tutorial command and was expecting to see a log file.  However it looks like I'm missing some jars?

Comment: You program didn't produced any log, because it even not found the main class to run, `Master`. Use a verbose option with your `java` command to see what is it really trying to load, for classes, and from where.